# Smart URLs using SQL table variable

Tags: php, sql, apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to know If it is possible to generate smart URLs through Apace mod-rewrite in a PHP website passing the value of a SQL variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that mod_rewrite is querying a database to generate the URL?

Comment: Yes, for example, I have the following URL (http://www.example.com/product.php?p=1) generated dinamically but I want to generate a URL like this http://www.example.com/red-car/ where "red-car" is the content of the variable pd_name in table product

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that would apply to
`/Customer/Detail/1234`
and map it to
`/Customer/Detail.php?ID=1234`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/Customer/Detail/([0-9]+)$  /Customer/Detail.php?ID=$1
```

You may want to consider a good MVC framework for other reasons in addition to automating this one.

Comment: I knew how to do It passing the variable in the URL through a post method, but, would It be possible without passing the variable in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do this! You'll need to get a table with "slugs" that are connected to the "ugly" URLs. A table with the columns "slug" (index) and "ugly_url" will probably do.

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$ redirect.php?slug=$1
```

redirect.php:

```
// You'll need to find out to wich ugly URL this Slug belongs to.
// Connect to your database ...
$slug = mysql_real_escape ( (string)$_GET['slug'] );
if ( empty ( $slug ) )
    die ( 'Page not found.' );

$query = mysql_query ( "SELECT `ugly_url` FROM `slugs` WHERE `slug` = $slug LIMIT 1" );
if ( !$query )
    die ( 'Page not found.' );

$fetch = mysql_fetch_array ( $query );

$ugly_url = $fetch['ugly_url'];
header ( "Location: $ugly_url" );
```

Comment: Will this work dinamically or do I have to manually link each ugly with Its slug?

Comment: You'll need to apply a slug for each ugly URL. But if you already have a field in a table you would like to use as slug, you can of course also use that!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think this actually will make what I'm looking for, I'll still get a url structure like this /redirect.php?slug=red-car when I want It to look like /red-car right?

Comment: The `mod_rewrite`-part actually shouldn't cause an HTTP-Redirect (except you force it to), but yes, the `header()`-function-call in the PHP does an HTTP-Redirect wich will force the URL to change... Maybe you could think about using `include` instead of `header()` in the PHP?

Comment: Thanks for your helo Andre, but I think there has to be an easier way to do this without an include, something more straight forward...

Comment: Depending on what setup you currently have, there sure would be more straight forward solutions.

For example, if you already have a table with e.g. different blog-posts, you simply could add slugs to them (or take an existing field as slug-field), and then map a beautiful URL like /hello-world/ to index.php?post=hello-world. You could then get the associated blog post by slug from the database (e.g. `SELECT FROM `posts` WHERE `slug` = $post LIMIT 1`).

But as I don't know your current setup, it's hard for me to help you any further.